# Javascript Auto-scroll Appears Jittery on Safari IOS

Tags: javascript, html, safari, smooth-scrolling

## The Objective

I am trying to make an auto-scrolling feature for an online ebook reader website. The user must be able to press a button and have the page scroll automatically.

## The problem

Every solution I have found so far uses either `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to scroll the page with `window.scrollBy(0, 1)`, and this works great on chrome, however when I test this on Safari IOS, the page does not scroll smoothly at all. It appears very jittery, to the point that the text is no longer legible.

[Here is a video demonstrating the problem.](https://youtu.be/fEhC6p3KmRI) (Please watch in 1080p60, since the jitter is more apparent at 60fps)

## The code

Here is a simple HTML document to demonstrate my current method of auto scrolling.

```js
            let scrollTimeout;

            function pageScroll() {
                scrollTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                    window.scrollBy(0, 1);
                    pageScroll();
                }, 10);
            }

            function startScroll() {
                pageScroll();
            }
            function stopScroll() {
                clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Test Auto-scroll</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 32px">
            <div style="position: sticky; top: 0">
                <button onclick="startScroll()">Start</button>
                <button onclick="stopScroll()">Stop</button>
            </div>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum
                ducimus, totam debitis sint modi inventore explicabo iusto
                assumenda vitae vero porro aperiam aut reiciendis nam culpa quia
                in, dolor quae.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Impedit sunt vitae saepe recusandae voluptatibus nihil enim,
                sequi rerum quibusdam nisi provident! Autem aliquid
                reprehenderit doloremque inventore quasi dolore fugit tempora.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure
                molestias consectetur molestiae labore totam ex et eum nulla
                officia, minima excepturi voluptates, consequatur amet modi!
                Molestiae autem illum ullam accusantium.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Quisquam ab ex tenetur a possimus? Cum, nostrum dolor? Veniam
                tenetur cupiditate, maxime fuga sequi earum excepturi
                repudiandae, aliquam, laborum blanditiis iusto.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam,
                laborum mollitia suscipit dolores omnis, cum perferendis rerum
                accusantium doloremque quasi pariatur, deserunt delectus et
                porro nesciunt cumque vel quisquam velit!
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Quisquam ab ex tenetur a possimus? Cum, nostrum dolor? Veniam
                tenetur cupiditate, maxime fuga sequi earum excepturi
                repudiandae, aliquam, laborum blanditiis iusto.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam,
                laborum mollitia suscipit dolores omnis, cum perferendis rerum
                accusantium doloremque quasi pariatur, deserunt delectus et
                porro nesciunt cumque vel quisquam velit!
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Quisquam ab ex tenetur a possimus? Cum, nostrum dolor? Veniam
                tenetur cupiditate, maxime fuga sequi earum excepturi
                repudiandae, aliquam, laborum blanditiis iusto.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam,
                laborum mollitia suscipit dolores omnis, cum perferendis rerum
                accusantium doloremque quasi pariatur, deserunt delectus et
                porro nesciunt cumque vel quisquam velit!
            </p>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just adding to this that its probably awful UX if you are trying to scroll for the reader, that is with the same spee as the user reads. I dont see how you are going to match that. That aside I dont know what the fix is, maybe try `window.scroll()` for absolute scrolling and see if it works differently.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point @Flame. There is one thing I noticed. When running the above snippet on IOS Safari, the behaviour is as expected. But when running it from my PC, I always seem to get the problem. The code is exactly the same, so I don't know what could be causing this issue.

Comment: Happend to have iPhone 13? This might be caused by the variable refresh rate of the screen. Maybe you could try having something invisible move on the screen fast while scrolling to try to fool iOS thinking it needs to refresh quicker. If nothing else works, maybe you could try implementing the scrolling, for example, by having the text in a very tall div and then animating the margin-top with CSS.

Comment: @Swiffy Yes the problem is on iPhone 13. I will definitely try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

###### Apple throttles their devices to give supposedly battery performance. But there are other reasons like Background App Refresh, Low Battery More, and many more. The easily visible reason is Low Power Mode **on** you will not get the same performance as Low Power More **off**.

With your snippet, you can clearly judge the performance difference between [Low Power Mode on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dDfb.jpg) and [Low Power Mode off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5k9t.jpg).

---

Also, performance can be affected by the display refresh rate. You can manage it with `requestAnimationFrame`, where you can somewhat control `fps`.

The below example could help you with `requestAnimationFrame`.

```js
let scrollAnimationFrame;
let prevtimeStamp = 0;
let deltaTime = 0;
let functionTiming = 10;
let counter = 0;
let reachedBottom = false;

function animateScroll(timestamp) {
  const deltaTime = timestamp - prevtimeStamp;
  prevtimeStamp = timestamp;
  const scrollY = window.scrollY;

  if(counter > functionTiming){
    window.scrollBy(0, 1);
    counter = 0;

    if(scrollY === window.scrollY)
      reachedBottom = true;
  }else{
    counter += deltaTime;
  }
  
  if(reachedBottom)
    cancelAnimationFrame(scrollAnimationFrame);
  else
    scrollAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animateScroll);
}

function startScroll() {
  if(!scrollAnimationFrame)
    animateScroll(0);
}

function stopScroll() {
  if(scrollAnimationFrame)
    cancelAnimationFrame(scrollAnimationFrame);
  scrollAnimationFrame = 0;
}

document.getElementById('functionTimingControl').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  functionTiming = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<main style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 32px">
    <div style="position: sticky; top: 0">
        <button onclick="startScroll()">Start</button>
        <button onclick="stopScroll()">Stop</button>
        <input type='number' min='1' max='1000' value='10' id='functionTimingControl' />
    </div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ducimus, totam debitis sint modi inventore explicabo iusto assumenda vitae vero porro aperiam aut reiciendis nam culpa quia in, dolor quae.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ducimus, totam debitis sint modi inventore explicabo iusto assumenda vitae vero porro aperiam aut reiciendis nam culpa quia in, dolor quae.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ducimus, totam debitis sint modi inventore explicabo iusto assumenda vitae vero porro aperiam aut reiciendis nam culpa quia in, dolor quae.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ducimus, totam debitis sint modi inventore explicabo iusto assumenda vitae vero porro aperiam aut reiciendis nam culpa quia in, dolor quae.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ducimus, totam debitis sint modi inventore explicabo iusto assumenda vitae vero porro aperiam aut reiciendis nam culpa quia in, dolor quae.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ducimus, totam debitis sint modi inventore explicabo iusto assumenda vitae vero porro aperiam aut reiciendis nam culpa quia in, dolor quae.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ducimus, totam debitis sint modi inventore explicabo iusto assumenda vitae vero porro aperiam aut reiciendis nam culpa quia in, dolor quae.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ducimus, totam debitis sint modi inventore explicabo iusto assumenda vitae vero porro aperiam aut reiciendis nam culpa quia in, dolor quae.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ducimus, totam debitis sint modi inventore explicabo iusto assumenda vitae vero porro aperiam aut reiciendis nam culpa quia in, dolor quae.
    </p>
</main>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem with this solution is that now it doesn't scroll at all on iOS. What do you think this problem is?